# Laravel relationship among 3 elements

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

The situation:

- a user can organize many parties
- a user can participate to many parties
- a user participating to a party has to declare what kind of stuff (food, cutlery, other) will take to that specific party

I was thinking to 3 models/tables, like: users, parties, equipment (maybe a better name, but I haven't yet decided), and in addition another table to put into relationship those 3 elements with 3 columns, one for each element's id, 
so that I can retrieve the informations needed, in example, given a party, know what each participant will take with him.

How do I represent this using Eloquent?
I was thinking to polymorphic relationships, but I couldn't come to a solution.

Am I thinking wrong to have what I need?

Answer (score 0):

With Eloquent I don't think you need another table. 3 tables will suffice - *users*, *parties* & *things*. To establish the relationships, you then use eloquent in respective models.

Example: In *User* model, you do something like

```
public function parties()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Party');
}

public function()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Thing');
}
```

In *Party* model,

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

With relationships set like that, you should be good to go.

Also check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Comment: I've got a problem with this. The many-to-many relationship between users and parties doesn't tell me who organised the party and who just participate to it. With that relationship "a party is organized by many users", but a party is organized by one user and many users participate to it.

Comment: I get you. That means you just change the _Party_ model to `$this->belongsTo('User')`. So, a Party belongs to a User and a User can have (participate in) many _Party_.